# Wordpress category displaying post meta instead of category

Tags: php, wordpress

Using Advanced Custom fields I've created a simple field that allows me to have a custom banner image of each page/post at the top of the page. My issue is that it's displaying the banner image of the most recent post at the top of the category page too. I'd like to be able to add a customized image for the categories but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Here is my code:

```
<?php if(is_front_page()) : ?>
    <div class="homepage-slider">
    <?php layerslider(1) ?>
    </div>
<?php else : ?>
    <?php
        if( get_field('banner_image'))
        {
            echo '<img src="';
            the_field('banner_image');
            echo '">';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '';
        }
    ?> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-images-for-categories/

Comment: I don't think that'll work. I can add an img directly to the category like that using acf as seen in this screenshot http://i.imgur.com/pcLLr5U.png

Comment: I can manually change it in the code to do an if this category output this image but I want to make it so that the user can manage it from the backend. I assume it has something to do with how the loop works because on my blog page I have a banner image assigned to the page and it's pulling the banner image from the first post http://taylorwalker.encorevisions.com/blog/